# How to copy from vim visually with terminator?

Tags: 14.04, vim, terminator

I would like to be able to visually select in vim in terminator, right click and copy whatever is highlighted to the clipboard. In OSX for example, I can do this by holding down the "alt" key and visually selecting and then copying. Is this possible in terminator? This might be more of a vim specific thing although I'm falling short.

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-xterm_clipboard
-xterm_save
```

Comment: Did you.. `set mouse=a`?

Comment: Yep I have that set in my .vimrc.

Comment: I think you'll have to get vim with xterm clipboard enabled - `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`, after which you can select with mouse, and the lines are copied to the X clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by holding down the "shift" key and selecting the text (this works with GNOME Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Example of copying one line of text between different terminals.

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to select the line
2. Type `"+y`
3. Select the other terminal (where you want to paste to)
4. Type `"+p`